# How to alter this code to allow appending to the list?

Tags: python, for-loop, debugging, while-loop, nested

I have an issue appending or in fact printing anything after this block of code:

```
reversedPriv = [52,27,13,6,3,2]
array= [9]
var = 0
numA = []
for i in array:
    for j in reversedPriv:
        while var!= j:
            if j < i:
                var = var + j
                numA.append(j)
                numA.sort()
print(numA)
```

I am expecting it to append [3,6] to numA and print but it currently does nothing. Is there some condition for the while loop that I'm overlooking?

The point of the code is to find which elements in 'reversedPriv' sum up to each element in 'array' and append them to the list 'numA'. For example from the list of 'reversedPriv' only 6 and 3 sum up to 9. So numA = [3,6] Currently 'array' only has a single element but the code should be able to scale it up for n number of elements.

Comment: `var` will never equals `j` so the while loop will never end

Comment: An infinite loop is there as var is not equal to elements of reversedPriv

Answer (score 1):

So in general, it's a good idea on SO to be clear about just what the question is, but it's often better to provide the context of your question.

What you are working on is a fragment of a knapsack solver.  As mentioned in my comments below, you may do better to just use or-tools out of the box as follows (taken from https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/knapsack):

```
from ortools.algorithms.pywrapknapsack_solver import KnapsackSolver

def knapsack():
    solver = KnapsackSolver(
       KnapsackSolver.KNAPSACK_MULTIDIMENSION_BRANCH_AND_BOUND_SOLVER,
      'KnapsackExample'
    )
    weights = [[52,27,13,6,3,2]]
    capacities = [9]

    solver.Init(weights[0], weights, capacities)
    computed_value = solver.Solve()

    packed_items = []
    packed_weights = []
    total_weight = 0
    print('Total value =', computed_value)
    for i in range(len(weights[0])):
        if solver.BestSolutionContains(i):
            packed_items.append(i)
            packed_weights.append(weights[0][i])
            total_weight += weights[0][i]

    print('Total weight:', total_weight)
    print('Packed items:', packed_items)
    print('Packed_weights:', packed_weights)

knapsack()
```

Console:

```
Total value = 9
Total weight: 9
Packed items: [3, 4]
Packed_weights: [6, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I only put a single element in the list for debugging but the code should run a list of 'n' elements. The aim of this code is decrypting a Knapsack algorithm. If for example array was array = [921, 1482, 1274, 1274, 1630] then I'm not sure this would work.

Comment: @socket_programmer, sorry - but if you want to use the < function across an array, then you only have to change limit = min(array).   I really want to help, but there's very little explanation as to what you are really trying to do with your numbers.  Maybe if you wrote out in plain what your inputs are and what you want to get out of it?

Comment: Sorry if it has been a bit convoluted, I edited the original post but I will post my edit again here: The point of the code is to find which elements in 'reversedPriv' sum up to each element in 'array' and append them to the list 'numA'. For example from the list of 'reversedPriv' only 6 and 3 sum up to 9. So numA = [3,6] Currently 'array' only has a single element but the code should be able to scale it up for n number of elements. Hope this helps more.

Comment: Ah. Is there a reason you cannot just use OR-Tools?  https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/python

Comment: Specifically https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `j` it should be `var != i`:

```
reversedPriv = [52,27,13,6,3,2]
array= [9]
var = 0
numA = []
for i in array:
    for j in reversedPriv:
        while var!= i:
            if j < i:
                var = var + j
                numA.append(j)
                numA.sort()
                break
            break
print(numA)
```

Or without the while,

```
reversedPriv = [52,27,13,6,3,2]
array= [9]
var = 0
numA = []
for i in array:
    for j in reversedPriv:
        if (var != i) and j < i:
            var = var + j
            numA.append(j)
numA.sort()
print(numA)
```

Or,

```
reversedPriv = [52,27,13,6,3,2]
array= [9]
var = 0
numA = []
numA = [sorted([x,y]) for x,y in zip(reversedPriv[:-1],reversedPriv[1:]) if x+y == array[0]][0]
print(numA)
```

Output:

```
[3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to do, but it'seems you want 6 + 3 = 9, append 6,3 to numA

```
for it1 in reversedPriv:
    for it2 in reversedPriv:

        sumit = it1 + it2     # sum 1st iteraction with 2nd iteraction

        if sumit == array[0]: #extract array value from list

            if it1 not in numA and it2 not in numA:
                numA.append(it1)
                numA.append(it2)

print(numA)
#[6, 3]
```