# How to find which elements in one array sum up to each element in the other?

Tags: python, arrays, list, debugging, encryption

Assuming:

```
reversedPriv = [52,27,13,6,3,2]
array= [9] #For this example we only used one element in the array, assume more elements
var = 0
numA = []
for i in array:
    for j in reversedPriv:
        while var!= j:
            if j < i:
                var = var + j
                numA.append(j)
                numA.sort()
print(numA)
```

I am expecting it to `append [3,6]` to `numA` and print but it currently does nothing. Is there some condition for the while loop that I'm overlooking?

The point of the code is to find which elements in `reversedPriv` sum up to each element in `array` and append them to the list `numA`. For example from the list of `reversedPriv` only 6 and 3 sum up to 9. So `numA = [3,6]` Currently 'array' only has a single element but the code should be able to scale it up for n number of elements.

Comment: What gives? [How to alter this code to allow appending to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170617/how-to-alter-this-code-to-allow-appending-to-the-list/59171005#59171005). Do not post same question multiple times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alter this code to allow appending to the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170617/how-to-alter-this-code-to-allow-appending-to-the-list)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pandas approach:

```
import itertools 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations( [52,27,13,6,3,2], 2))  
nums = [9] 
df['sum'] = df[0] + df[1] 
matches=[] 
for num in nums: 
    matches.append(list(df.loc[df['sum'] == num][0]) + list(df.loc[df['sum'] == num][1])) 

matches
# [[6, 3]]
```